# Not getting Dynapaint to work in 2.81a

Tags: dynamic-paint

Been trying to get dynapaint to paint weights using a brush on a canvas but it is not showing up or doing anything. When i turn on displace it works fine. 
[image]

I linked the brush, saved the file, cached, tried diff settings, everything...
Any help appreciated.

Sure thing, the cube(brush) moves in the surface of the sphere
[image]

nothing i try works it seems
[image]

Comment: Could you also show the paint brush settings of the cube ? Also, if you are using Blender 2.81 or up there is a "vertex color" node to easily access them.

Comment: done, can share the blend file as well
tried adding the vertex colors but that didn't end well

Comment: You need to actually add a vertex group to the sphere named dp_weight, did you do that ? This would explain why it doesn't appear in the vertex color node. Else I'd be interested in testing your project file

Comment: Hi Nathan, i have a vertex group but i can't select it, tried to make another but it can't be selected either.. i wonder if bugs are involved or not. tried so much it might just be me.
If you want you can have a look at both my tests, maybe you see what's going on. Cheers for helping sofar m8
https://we.tl/t-jOKHr3DLd2

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem, you need to set the surface type to Vertex Paint, not Vertex Weight. See in the output, it is asking you for a vertex Group, not a Vertex Color Layer.
A vertex Weight is a value (0...1) while a vertex color is a color (R,G,B)
On my end after I have entered the correct vertex color layer name, the color is updated when I tap Tab 2 times to go in and out of edit mode.

Comment: Oh, i'll try that and get back to you, thanks Nathan

Comment: tested the paint thing but still no selectable vertexgroups, i will do another test from scratch to see what's going one, clueless